# Aurelia on shared hosting

Tags: aurelia

I was wondering if it is possible to run an Aurelia project on a shared hosting where there's no access to ssh, no NodeJS (and of course no `gulp watch` or anything else) with only PHP available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was wondering if it is possible to run an Aurelia project on a
>   shared hosting where there's no access to ssh?

[SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) has nothing to do with [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/latest/doc/article/what-is-aurelia). SSH is for remotely logging in to another computer.

> I was wondering if it is possible to run an Aurelia project on a
>   shared hosting where there's no access to no NodeJS?

[Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/about/) has nothing to do with Aurelia. Node.js is a JavaScript runtime environment designed for asynchronous eventing within network applications. Aurelia is a client side environment that may optionally talk with a Node.js enabled server to retrieve server side data.

> I was wondering if it is possible to run an Aurelia project on a
>   shared hosting where there's no access to gulp?

[Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp) is essentially a task runner to automate things such as the minification of CSS and JavaScript files; the bundling of files; basically the repetative and tedious tasks you would perform by hand to prepare your web application for production (amongst other things).

> I was wondering if it is possible to run an Aurelia project on a
>   shared hosting with only PHP available?

[PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/intro-whatis.php) has nothing to do with Aurelia. PHP is a server side scripting language designed for web development that can be used to server up information to the web client. Aurelia is a client side environment that may optionally talk with PHP to retrieve server side data.

> What about ES6 / Typscript?

Aurelia, Angular 2, plain old JavaScript, etc... all can be written in ECMA 2016 or TypeScript. The transpiler, i.e., Babel or the TypeScript transpiler, will convert the code into ECMA 2015 to be compliant with today's browsers.

I'd recommend reading the Aurelia documentation, playing with the sample Aurelia skeletons, and maybe even viewing the 2 Aurelia courses on PluralSight which do a great job at introducing the Aurelia framework as well as most of the questions you've posed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible. Aurelia is pure javascript and requires no server side technology to run. However, you would probably want some way to feed your Aurelia models with data from your back-end. PHP is as good a choice as any.

Comment: What about the ES6 syntax or Typescript implemented in Aurelia? Do they work without back-end?

Comment: Yes they do because they are "transpiled" to ecmascript 5. You develop in es6/7 or typescript, but they run as ecmascript 5